# How to reload the current page once without changing the URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript code to set a language cookie for users when they visit my site:

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
    var expires = "";
    if(expires) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while(c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if(c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function delCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name+'=; expires=Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT; path=/'; // expires=-1
}

// After the page has finished loading, check that the user already has a language cookie?
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage;
    lang = lang.slice(0, 2).toLowerCase();
    if(!getCookie('language')) { // If not, set language cookie
        if(lang == 'vi') {
            setCookie('language', 'vi');
        }
        else {
            setCookie('language', 'en');
        }
    }
    if(getCookie('language')) { // If the user already has a language cookie
        if(getCookie('language') != 'vi' || getCookie('language') != 'en') { // If the user's language cookie is not supported
            setCookie('language', 'en'); // Then use English as the default
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Now, I want after setting the language cookie for the user, the current page will be reloaded once without changing the URL (without adding the hash `#`, parameter,...).

I tried setting the cookie, then using `location.reload()`, once reloading will delete that cookie as follows:

```
// ... Skip Cookie Code ...
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage;
    lang = lang.slice(0, 2).toLowerCase();
    if(!getCookie('language')) {
        if(lang == 'vi') {
            setCookie('language', 'vi');
            setCookie('needreload', 'yes');
        }
        else {
            setCookie('language', 'en');
            setCookie('needreload', 'yes');
        }
    }
    if(getCookie('language')) {
        if(getCookie('language') != 'vi' || getCookie('language') != 'en') {
            setCookie('language', 'en');
            setCookie('needreload', 'yes');
        }
    }
    if(getCookie('needreload') == 'yes') {
        location.reload();
        delCookie('needreload');
    }
}, false);
```

However, that makes my website reload constantly, infinite times instead of just once.

Please show me the method to solve this problem. I would appreciate the solution you give!

Comment: It might be because you are not deleting needreload cookie or setting it to false? everytime its present and everytime its getting refreshed. Thought?

Comment: @Supercool. I have updated the cookie name in the post, `fc_reload` is `needreload`, I have not edited it before posting the question. I have updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, is the code check the user's language cookie is supported have problem. I have to use `&&` instead of `||` over there. If I use `||` then it is always `true` even if the user's language cookie is supported, resulting in an infinite page reload loop. Here is the code that worked fine:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage;
    lang = lang.slice(0, 2).toLowerCase();
    if(!getCookie('language')) {
        if(lang == 'vi') {
            setCookie('language', 'vi');
        }
        else {
            setCookie('language', 'en');
        }
        setCookie('needreload', '1');
    }
    if(getCookie('language')) { // If it already exists
        if(getCookie('language') != 'vi' && getCookie('language') != 'en') { // Use && instead of || will make it work
            setCookie('language', 'en');
            setCookie('needreload', '1');
        }
    }
    if(getCookie('language') == '1') {
        location.reload();
        delCookie('needreload');
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting value of `needreload` cookie to `"no"` before you do `location.reload()`

```
if(getCookie('needreload') == 'yes') {
        setCookie('needreload', 'no');
        location.reload();
        delCookie('fc_reload');
      //im not sure delCookie fc_reload will be executed 
      //as page will pe refreshed and control goes off
 }
```

Comment: I have updated the cookie name in the post, `fc_reload` is `needreload`, I have not edited it before posting the question.

Comment: In that cases delete cookie before location.reload

Comment: I wrote the code as below, but the looping phenomenon is still happening!
`delCookie('needreload');` `location.reload();`

Comment: Try setting to needreload cookie to no before reloading

Comment: I tried setting the `needreload` cookie to `no`, then `location.reload` and finally `delCookie('needreload')` but it still reloaded the page continuously!